# Getting CORS when calling `https://login.tapkey.com/connect/token`

Tags: tapkey

When I attempt to make a call to `https://login.tapkey.com/connect/token` using a code returned in the authentication stage from the client I get a CORS error, I however I'm able to make that call from the BackenEnd.

Answer (score 1):

CORS applies only to browser clients. That's the nature of CORS restrictions and what they should prevent.

Make sure that you setup the correct hostname in the client configuration in the developer section.

[image: Screenshot]